# SQL Convert function returns error 241

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a column in my DB with varchar type having values in following format Day Mon dd hh:mm:ss EDT YYYY. I need to convert it to date time.

On running query `select CONVERT(datetime, colname, 100)` system returns Error code 241.

Help Please

Comment: can you post a sample of the date in your table?

Comment: Yes, post data and tell us wich version of SQL Server are you using

Comment: Thanks. here is the sample value Sat May 05 12:38:00 EDT 2012

Comment: Why is your date stored as a string? This is one of the many problems that result from this technique. You will encounter more, I promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for this:

```
declare @date varchar(50)
set @date = 'Sat May 05 12:38:00 EDT 2012'

select cast(substring(@date, 5, 6) + ' ' + right(@date, 4) + ' ' + substring(@date, 12, 8) as datetime)
```

OR

```
select cast(substring(@date, 5, 7) + right(@date, 4) + substring(@date, 11, 9) as datetime)
```

OR

```
select convert(datetime, substring(@date, 5, 7) + right(@date, 4)  + substring(@date, 11, 9))
```

result:

```
2012-05-05 12:38:00.000
```